# Browser is not getting redirected with res.sendFile()

Tags: node.js, redirect, express, sendfile

In my Express app, when the admin sucessfully logs in, I want him to be sent to his dashboard page. So in the `post` function, on success, I redirect to `admin/` which takes him to the next function

So I have:

```
adminRoutes.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log("/", path.join(__dirname, 'public/admin/index.html'));

    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/admin/index.html'), {}, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(err.status).end();
      }
      else {
          console.log('Sent:');
      }
  });
});
```

But the problem is, nothing happens in my browser. It just stays on the browser page. It doesn't change to the new page I'm sending.

Why is it not working?

Comment: Are you getting to the log "Sent:" in your console?

Comment: @laggingreflex Yes I am. That's what's bugging me out

Answer (score 1):

You should do a `redirect` not `sendFile`. `sendFile` is for telling the browser to download a specific file. Try:

```
res.redirect('public/admin');
```

Also, make sure this is registered in your routes. The route should then `render` the HTML.

Comment: and what's at the route `public/admin`? At some point, I've gotta send a file

Comment: Do you mean a downloadable file? Or a file rendered as HTML? These are two radically different concepts to the browser